# React routeer is causing a blank index page. Next JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js, react-router-dom

I'm creating a website, and I want the users to be directed to a specific page when they open the site. The page they are going to be directed to depends on if they already logged in. My problem is: the router doesn't work (**user is not redirected to any page**) and all that appears is a blank page. I've tried to get rid of the routes, but even though, I couldn't display anything on the index page. Maybe the problem is not even the router, but something else.

I never get any error messages. Here are the parts of the code, where I think the problem may be.

_app.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Novidades from './lancamento'
import SignUp from './signup'
import Croosa from './croosa'
import { AuthProvider } from '../utils/auth'
import PrivateRoute from '../utils/PrivateRoute'


const App = () => {
  return(
        <AuthProvider>
          <Router>
            <div>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/lancamento' component={Lancamento} />
              <Route exact path='/croosa' component={Croosa}/>
              <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import App from './_app'

export default function Home() {
      return(
        <App/>
      )
}
```

And the PrivateRoute.js, which decides to which page the user is going to be redirected:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/signup"} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}


export default PrivateRoute
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake(s).

Answer (score 2):

Next.js uses a filesystem based routing structure.

You have a misunderstanding of how the `_app.js` file works. It's the parent component that is responsible for rendering the other components that get exported from other pages.

For example: if my `_app.js` file looks like this:

```js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>This was injected by _app.js</p>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        <div>
    );
}
```

and my `pages/index.js` file looks like this:

```js
export default function Hello(){
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>
}
```

With that setup if I visit the `localhost:3000/` then the following will get rendered

```
<div>
    <p>This was injected by _app.js</p>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

What you did instead is in your `_app.js` you ignored the `Component` property that was passed and so on every page you visit the same content will be rendered. That is:

```js
<AuthProvider>
  <Router>
    <div>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/lancamento" component={Lancamento} />
      <Route exact path="/croosa" component={Croosa} />
      <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    </div>
  </Router>
</AuthProvider>
```

The reason your index page is blank is because you didn't set up a route for `/` and so no component will be rendered by react router on that page. Regardless I suggest you stop using react router and start using the built in routing system with next.js

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes you suggested, it worked perfectly. I'll see if I will keep using routes on this project. If I decide so, I'll certainly use next/router this time.